# the superior's desire

Tags: nominalization

I realized that I could use an adjective with a definite article to nominalize that adjective. Like this;

The rich should help the poor.

And I wrote these sentences;

> *The superior's* desire to subjugate their subordinates is a perpetual
>   tradition.
>
> *The superior* are usually blamed for that.

Is my nominalization understandable? A native speaker could not recognize the purpose of it, that's why I am asking.

It does not refer to a superior, which is a standardized noun form.

Comment: I would use the noun "superior", superiors' desire ...

Comment: That connotes a sense of workplace. In my sentence, I am referring to all those that have the upper hand in some type of hierarchy, like money, social rank, etc.

Comment: Pretty ugly English, if you ask me. "The superiors are usually blamed for subordination," although grammatically correct is still not pretty.

Comment: @HowardPautz I just said "the superior" not "the superiors".

Comment: @HowardPautz It was about social problems, so the superior means socially dominant. It also incorporates race and everything else.

Comment: Well, your sentence structures implied otherwise: "their" and "are"  (and I do have a superior enough knowledge of English to know the variants of superior. LOL)

Comment: @HowardPautz I don't quite get it. Like "the rich are", "the superior are". Note here that I did not say "the superiors are". I deliberately tried to avoid using the standardized noun form, because what I was implying with "the superior" was more encompassing.

Comment: why get stuck with the word? If you mean "socially elite," "the financial one percent," why not just say so?

Comment: Because that is not what I wrote and I am trying to determine the legitimacy of what I wrote.

Comment: ok - what's more important? Being enamored with a phrase, or writing something your readers will understand? You said a native speaker didn't understand it. I'm a native - and frequently a professional writer. I understand what you want to say, but it comes off as somewhat stilted. "A superior's desire to subjugate is traditional."  Though ugly, it would suffice. "Their /his/her subordinates" is superfluous ... you have to have others to subordinate. And, "perpetual" is also unnecessary as tradition by its nature is perpetual. Less words, more sense.

Comment: @HowardPautz I understand your stance. However, I am asking about nominalization, and that is the point of my question. As well as deciding phrase "the superior"'s legitimacy, I am hoping to find if I can use other nominalized adjectives here, such as "_the dominant's_ desire" or "_the dominant are_".

Comment: Did you check the definitions of [*superior*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/superior)? It is usually used as an adjective, not a noun. And when it is a noun, it usually refers to an individual. You could write something like "the superior (people) are ...", but as written it is very unnatural sounding. Better to add what is "superior".

Comment: @user3169. Yes, it is usually used as an adjective. Rich is used as an adjective, too, but when you put the before it, it becomes "the rich", referring to people that are rich. I sought to have the same effect with "the superior".

Comment: Well,  trying to normalize something that's klunky from the start is problematic. You can't normalize malformed data. Maybe take a breather and search for a superior sentence structure. :))

Comment: The problem is that *rich* by itself can be used as a collective noun, but *superior* by itself cannot. It would be good to find some actual examples and add to your question. According to the definitions I don't think it works.

Comment: @user3169 I can easily imagine reading, in a sociological screed, a sentence such as: _The superior have always lorded it over the inferior._ I wouldn't bat an eye. The OP is concerned with nominalization, and context is indispensible to the concept, I think. Any adjective can be nominalized given the proper context.

Comment: @P.E.Dant As it happens, it was a paper criticizing southern aristocracy. The sentences provided above as examples are not my actual sentences.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike the other European languages I know, English is very picky about using adjectives as nouns.

The basic 'rule' is that we usually use an adjective this way only when it has been established as a "category" in the current discourse. Unlike, say, Latin or German, English is uncomfortable with using an adjective as the name of a category without proper introduction. For instance, if you've already introduced the idea that there are two sorts of people, *superior* and *subordinate*, it's acceptable to say something like *The superior degrade and humiliate the subordinate*. But seeing sentences like yours by themselves, without that sort of context, is jarring.

It's even more jarring to use an adjective as a nominal designating an individual—*the ADJ*. *The Red* is fine as an epithet (*Eirik the Red*), and a bare adjective can act as a nickname (*'Red' Grange*), but we're uncomfortable with *The Red* by itself: Dürrenmatt's *Der Blinde* has to be translated *The Blind **Man***, and Stendahl's novel *Le Rouge et le Noir* gives translators the heebie-jeebies.

There are a few adjectives used so frequently as categorial names that they need no introduction—the rich, the poor, the saved, the damned, and (if you're into Plato) the good and the beautiful. But I'd be very careful adopting this use.

Comment: @whitedevil - StoneyB found the word I was looking for to describe the sentences: *jarring.*  ++ Excellent explainer.

Comment: Thank you StoneyB. I never knew that there are only few I can use!

Comment: @StoneyB Is the representation _ADJ_ acceptable to The People's Front of Judea, the Judean People's Front, the Campaign for a Free Galilee, and the Judean Popular People's Front? If so, we have an ort to begin with!

Comment: My first thought on reading the OP's sentences was that this might have something to do with ecclesiastical office.

Answer (score 0):

I could easily see a sentence like the first one in a how-to manual for abbots. In religious hierarchies, the term **superior** has the meaning you intend.  You may also be familiar with the term **Mother Superior** to refer to the nun who runs the convent.

However, "the superior are" is not how we'd refer to the class of individuals who occupy positions of power and responsibility in some religious hierarchy. We'd use the plural and say "Superiors are..." or "The desire of superiors to subjugate..."

Again, though, to use the term "Superiors" in a *secular* context would be highly unusual nowadays in egalitarian English-speaking democracies; in secular contexts the phrase "their superiors" would be taken to mean "their betters", that is, those who are in a higher social class.